# Differentiate SQL Server Express from SQL Server installed in a server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I own a VPS server and I was told SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition was installed on Windows OS 2008R2.

When I opened the SQL Server configuration manager I saw this:

[image]

1. I thought I should see only the SQL Server Express but there is also SQL Server (`MSSQLServer`). Does that mean both SQL Server Express and SQL Server of different version are installed? If so how will I know which version of SQL Server and SQL Server Express are installed ?
2. I also see SQL Server full text filter daemon service running which means full text is installed but unfortunately when I right click the table I see the full text index is disabled.

[image]

I am confused as to what is installed and what is not installed. Can some one throw a light on this one

When I connect to the default instance with servername as `.`
I get :

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) Jun 28 2012 08:36:30
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>   Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 
>   (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

When I connect to the instance with servername as `machinename\sqlexpress` 
I get:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) Jun 28 2012 08:36:30
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>   Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 
>   (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Yes both SQL Server default instance, which can be any version of SQL Server, and express instance are installed.

Comment: you can check the version using SELECT @@VERSION after connecting to both default and express instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MSSQLSERVER` name in the services does not mean anything other than SQL Server (*any* edition) was installed as the **default** (unnamed) instance. It does ***NOT*** give you any information as to what version or edition it is! This *can be* SQL Server **Express**!

You need to connect to that database instance and run

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

to find out what exact version/edition it is.

Having the two `SQL Server` service entries just means you have **two** instances - which **edition** each instance is cannot be determined from their names alone. OK - `SQLEXPRESS` is the default name used for SQL Server Express - but you *could* install a Standard or Enterprise edition with that instance name - just for fun.

Comment: updated my answer. It looks both the versions are sql-epxress, One with advanced services and other which is not.

Comment: install Standart and name it Express indeed sounds fun

Comment: @RayofCommand: it might violate the *Principle of Least Surprise* - but it's *possible* ! :-)